# why am I not able to see the margin property in my html page?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am trying to design something but even on adding the margin property I am not able to see the changes.
Below is my html code.

```css
.side {
  background-color: teal;
  display: inline;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Task Managment To-do list</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3 offset-s1">
    <header class="side" id="day">Date Section</header>
  </div>
  <div class="col s2 offset-s3">
    <header class="side">
      Navigations
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either try this or change `inline` to `block` or `inline-block`

```css
.side {
  background-color: teal;
  display: inline;
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 400%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Task Managment To-do list</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3 offset-s1">
    <header class="side" id="day">Date Section</header>
  </div>
  <div class="col s2 offset-s3">
    <header class="side">
      Navigations
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of just `display: inline;`, because `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` does not work with inline elements

```css
.side {
  background-color: teal;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Task Managment To-do list</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3 offset-s1">
    <header class="side" id="day">Date Section</header>
  </div>
  <div class="col s2 offset-s3">
    <header class="side">
      Navigations
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```